# How would to lazy load components on scroll?

Tags: angular, components, lazy-loading, angular-components

That's pretty much it.

I get how to load component using the rooter but let's say i have a footer component with a google map.

I don't want it to be loaded at first load since the user won't see it.

But i would like to load at some point.

How can i do that ?

Comment: `*ngIf` is to hide it until something.

Comment: Just a quick note: `*ngIf` isn't actually to "hide" it but rather to completely add/remove it from the DOM.

Comment: To achieve this, you could use `HostListener` to monitor the `scroll` event and detect when your item is about to come in to view. Take a look at [this implementation](https://github.com/anagram4wander/ng-vfor-lib/blob/master/projects/ng-vfor-lib/src/lib/core/directives/ng-vFor-container.directive.ts#L39) for a virtualized grid. One other option is [intersection observer](https://blog.angularindepth.com/a-modern-solution-to-lazy-loading-using-intersection-observer-9280c149bbc). Take a look at [ng-defer-load](https://github.com/TradeMe/ng-defer-load).

Comment: @Dean i'm gonna take a look at your links about intersection observer api, it seems interesting, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be out of the scope of your question, but native lazy-loading for images and iframes will be supported from Chrome ~75 onwards. According to this [blog post](https://addyosmani.com/blog/lazy-loading/) by Addy Osmani (who works on Chrome), lazy-loading can be enabled by using the `loading` attribute:

```
<img src="celebration.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="..." />
<iframe src="video-player.html" loading="lazy"></iframe>
```

I am not sure when will it be released for production, but I am pretty excited by this new attribute, as this will mean that we will save a ton of JavaScript/TypeScript code, and reduce the need for any other external dependencies.

Nonetheless, if you are curious to track the progress of the implementation of the `loading` attribute, feel free to pop by this [post](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fbclid=IwAR1C9bkEAK7oTJ8-Pv1j0QMOToMra4vl4rIwWvw44YM5f9764yg7RFFJJf8#!topic/blink-dev/jxiJvQc-gVg). There is plenty of discussion on it.

Adoption:

> **Interoperability and Compatibility**
>
> Firefox: No public signals
>
> Edge: No public signals
>
> Safari: Some public support A WebKit developer has
> mentioned that Apple is interested in this kind of feature and is a
> reviewer on the LazyLoad spec pull request.
>
> Web developers: Positive
> signals A thread on WICG about lazy loading images